# Why is my nav link still underlined? Even with !important declaration

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm not sure if this may be due to php/wordpress but I've got a nav bar that I just realised when you click the link it stays underlined until you hover it again? Seems strange to me I've never had this happen and can't quite work out why..

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src=" " height="10%" width="10%"/>Link 1</a></li>

      <li><a href="#"><img src=" " height="10%" width="10%"/><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>

      <li><a href="#"><img src="" height="10%" width="10%"/><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

scss..

```
nav {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: $nav_bgcolor;
  box-shadow: $nav_shadow;

   ul {
    color: #979797;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
   ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  }
   ul li a {
    color: $font_color;
  }
   ul li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $hover;
  }
   a, a:visited, a:active, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: underlines can come in many forms... borders, box-shadows, etc. etc.  Try adding `border-bottom: 0 !important` and `box-shadow: none !important`.

Comment: Didn't work :/ , but thank you

Comment: try changing your css rule to be more specific perhaps?  like this instead:  `ul > li > a, ul > li > a:visited, ul > li > a:active, ul > li > a:visited, ul > li > a:focus, ul > li > a:hover, ul > li`

Comment: It could be also that a border is being added to the image instead... in which case, you'll need to target the `img` tag.

Comment: Sadly no luck, I can't even inspect what its doing as once I go into it.. It disappears

Comment: Not that either..

Comment: I rolled the question back to its original post. Please don't add "CLOSED" to it. Accepting an answer does that for you.

Comment: Ohh okay, sorry I'm really new to stack overflow. Still understanding how it works

Answer (score 0):

change your " `ul li a`" , to this:

```
nav ul li a {
color: $font_color;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code above was actually correct in fixing the problem I had. The problem was happening as it wasn't updating any of my code as the browser had cached the site.
Thanks everyone for your help

NOTE: Delete browser history!!

Answer (score 0):

You Need some HTML Fixes.
You have used `anchor` tag inside `anchor` tag.

HTML

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="" height="10%" width="10%"/>Link 1
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="" height="10%" width="10%"/>Link 2
        </a>
       </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="" height="10%" width="10%"/>Link 3
        </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
/*Random colors use your colors here*/
$nav_bgcolor:red;
$nav_shadow:black;
$font-color:white;
$hover:green;

/*Random colors use your colors here*/

nav {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: $nav_bgcolor;
  box-shadow: $nav_shadow;

   ul {
    color: #979797;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
   ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  }
   ul li a {
    color: $font_color;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
   ul li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $hover;
  }
   a, a:visited, a:active, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it happened when posting my question as I was removing some things, like the php call to add in an img. Basically i was shortening the code and i thought I cleared the <a> but it was there all along thank you.